# Comment timer resets on invalid comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, rate-limiting

When you write a comment which isn't long enough, then edit it so it is long enough, when you first initially attempted to submit the comment it set the last comment posted timer, so you have to wait 15 seconds to actually post your valid comment.

Shouldn't invalid comments that don't get accepted not reset the 15 second comment timer?

I probably think I'm normal but actually I'm living in a world where I am really thick without realising it, but I keep running into this annoying counter every now and then!

Comment: Sadly, this is `[status-bydesign]`

Comment: Look at the list of related questions - you're not alone.